# How to get data exported into excel from Postgres using nodeJs terminal?

Tags: node.js, excel, postgresql, export-to-excel

I need to create NodeJS module that will export data from query(Postgres) into excel file. 
 This module should start from terminal line like "node index.js id = (some id)"
I do have query from db.
 - How to realize this module ? I am breaking my head for 2 days now...

Comment: You should be asking specific questions here. This is way too broad, without any problem explained.